# Is it possible to get a diagonal subset symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'm asking if I can get the subset symbol, or any symbol really for that matter if possible, for LaTeX, namely the subset symbol would have symmetry about the line y=x. If you know what I mean.

Comment: \begin{rotate}{**angle**} or \begin{turn}{**angle**} doesn't work for SE.math post compiler.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, however are you asking about TeX or MathJax (which does not use TeX)?  MathJax questions are not really on topic on this site: for tex the answer you put in the comment is the answer, mathjax questions are best asked on the [mathjax help forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users)

Comment: I see, well what about putting symbols aside (left or right) of a symbol?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. symbols naturally are laid out side by side. Also you didn't answer if you are looking for TeX answers or answers for MathJax (as used on the math.se site)

Answer (score 8):

How about using the `graphicx` package, and then `\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\subseteq$}`? I don't know how to include examples of output here though, but that seems to be what you require.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\dsubseteq}{\mathrel{
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\subseteq$}}
}

\begin{document}

\[ A \dsubseteq B \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: depending on the use of the symbol, you might want to wrap this in `\mathop`, `\mathbin`, or whatever is appropriate.